# Monopoly Deal - JSN Card

Tags: monopoly-deal

If you steal a property and your opponent doesn't play their JSN card at that time, then you lay a matching property down to make a complete set, and then your third card is to charge rent - can your opponent then decide to use his JSN card to take his property card back, or is the JSN card only good to get out of paying the rent at this point?

Answer (score 3):

The time to play "Just Say No" is when the action they want to "Say No" to is happening. If they didn't stop you taking their property, and you're now claiming rent, then they can only "Say No" to the rent.

(This is assuming that you didn't rush through all three plays so quickly they didn't have time to react.)